# jvm using SO_RCVBUF larger than system maximum

Tags: java, linux, posix

On a Linux (Ubuntu/x64) I've verified that the max `SO_RCVBUF` is

```
~$ cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max
212992
```

However when I run the code below the default socket receive size is `530904`.

```
SocketChannel ss = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9876));
ss.configureBlocking(false);
//ss.socket().setReceiveBufferSize(10*1024*1024);
System.out.println("Receive size:"+ ss.socket().getReceiveBufferSize());
```

What's strange is if I uncomment the `setReceiveBufferSize` line above the output changes to

```
Receive size:212992
```

i.e. JVM default receive size is above the system max but it won't let me set a size above max.

Does anyone know what's going on here?